# Filtering elements in TransformMessage in Mulesoft

Tags: mule-component, dataweave, mule-esb

I have below xml payload.

```
<ClientList>
<Client>
    ............................
    ....n number of elements....
    ............................
    <EmployerList>
        <Employer>
            ............................
            ....n number of elements....
            ............................
            <LocationList>
                <Location></Location>
                <Location></Location>
                <Location></Location>

        <Employer>
            ............................
            ....n number of elements....
            ............................
            <LocationList>
                <Location></Location>
                <Location></Location>
                <Location></Location>

<Client>
    ............................
    ....n number of elements....
    ............................
    <EmployerList>
        <Employer>
            ............................
            ....n number of elements....
            ............................
            <LocationList>
                <Location></Location>
                <Location></Location>
                <Location></Location>

        <Employer>
            ............................
            ....n number of elements....
            ............................
            <LocationList>
                <Location></Location>
                <Location></Location>
                <Location></Location>
```

Location has locationId element. Based on input locationId which i have in hand, I need to filter only the location. How can I completely remove non matching location elements without iterating/remapping thousands of other elements (mentioned as "n number of elements")

Answer (score 0):

Provided xml is not very clear, possible solutions are:
1. you can use the xpath filter. eg: .

Reference: https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/using-xpath-expressions-on-an-xml-document-with-namespaces/
2. You can also using jaxb. convert xml to Java Bean and filter based on desired location and create new xml file with filter details(only if required).